# Intergrating Scala Case Classes with Java Spring MVC

Tags: scala, spring-mvc

I'm using Scala Slick for my data models. Requesting a list of all events to

```
@RequestMapping("/events")
public @ResponseBody List<Event> getAllEvents() {
    return JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(Events.getAllEvents());
}
```

Returns the JSON object `[{}]`, which means there is one event in the database, but it's not parsed correctly.

`Event` is a case class and looks like this:

```
case class Event(id:Option[Long] = None, name:String, companyId:Long, zoneMappingId:Long, startDate:DateTime, endDate:DateTime)
```

How can I fix this incorrect parsing? Do I have to use something like json4s to parse it in Scala. If so, how would I do that?

Comment: How does this relate to Slick?

Comment: It doesn't, you're right. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2):

Annotate your case class fields with scala.beans.BeanProperty

```
case class Event(@BeanProperty id:Option[Long] = None, @BeanProperty name:String, @BeanProperty companyId:Long, @BeanProperty zoneMappingId:Long, @BeanProperty startDate:DateTime, @BeanProperty endDate:DateTime)
```

(Not sure if that works for the option, though)